# Which system table holds the descriptions of system errors?

Tags: sql-server

Looking for the system table that holds the descriptions of errormsgs < 50000

Had no luck going through the contents of sys.objects with type_desc 'system_table'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The answer actually depends on your version of SQL Server, which you didn't mention:

```
-- SQL 2000
select * from sysmessages where error < 50000
-- SQL 2005+
select * from sys.messages where message_id < 50000
```

See the documentation for more details: [`sysmessages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260433%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [`sys.messages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187382.aspx)

Comment: version is SQL2005+ and the aim is to edit a system error message

Comment: So your real question is how to edit a system error message? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The question is 'what is the name of the system table'. The reason behind my need to edit the system message is security-related.

Comment: And I answered that question. But you can't update system tables anyway, as you have hopefully found out already through experimentation: `begin tran; update sys.messages set text = 'oops' where message_id = 21 and language_id = 1033; rollback;`. Note also the documentation: you [should not try to change any system tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179932.aspx) and updating system tables was [disabled in SQL2005 and higher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179262.aspx). This is why it's always better to explain your real goal: someone may have an alternative solution.

Comment: You can update system tables dude, but you need to know the names first - hence the post.

Comment: In SQL Server 2014 I fire this query - `select * from sys.sysmessages where error <  50000`

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    master.dbo.sysmessages
```

Comment: sysmessages is not a system table though

Comment: @JohnAlan strictly speaking, `sysmessages` and `sys.messages` are system views (or catalog views), which get data from system table `sys.sysusermsgs`. However, have you actually tried selecting directly from any of those system tables?

Comment: @TimLehner `sysmessages` [is (or was) indeed a system table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260604(v=sql.80).aspx) but `sys.messages` is a [catalog view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx).

Comment: @Pondlife the OP's "sys.objects with type_desc 'system_table'" indicates to me that we're looking at SQL Server 2005 or above. As such, `sysmessages` is a view that selects data from `sys.sysusermsgs`, at least according sp_help, SSMS Object Explorer, and the execution plan.  But yes, `sysmessages` was a system table in SQL Server 2000. I think the OP wants to now select directly from a table, which would seem to be a problem.

Comment: Guys I know that they are system views. I need to edit an errormessage, so I need to find first the systable name (then -m, DAC etc)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a brick wall here.
Internal function OpenRowset(TABLE SYSERRORS) is easy to use for reading system tables (using the DAC) but for updates it needs arguments that are totally undocumented outside Microsoft.